# The strategy of row player in $2\times 2$ ordinal game

Tags: game-theory

I am proving the simplest part of theory of moves. Assume that both players are rational, and consider the following $2\times 2$ ordinal game:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
(3,3) && (2,4) \\
(4,2) && (1,1)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Then if I start from (1.1), and Row stays (2.4) or moves to (1.1), then does row have to move? It seems that it is better for row to move from (1.1) to (2.4) but it is also better for column.

Put simply, If Row starts from (1.1) and has two choices: moves to (2.4) or stays at (1.1). If Row is rational, then does he have to move or stay?

Comment: This is very unclear. What's happening? What are $1.1$ and $2.4$? Are these payoffs in the $2 \times 2$ matrix? Do you mean $(1,1)$ and $(2,4)$? What's the rest of the matrix?

Comment: it is game of chicken, The rest columns are  (3.3) (2.4) (4.2) (1.1)

Comment: (3.3) (2.4) on top and (4.2) (1.1) on bottom and usual 2x2 game model